# Best Practise for custom home page

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.0.1

Creating a theme for a site I am working on and would like to know what would be the best solution for my problem.

On the home page I would like a full width slider under the header ( I have the header all built). Under the slider I would like a left column which has the navigation for product categories and the main body to the right of that with Sale and Clearance items product view.

I'm not sure if possible but should I set the home page as a 2 column and add the slider in or make the homepage a one column and do it that way.

If I do do it one of these ways what would be the best way to implement the slider.

I'm using CE lastest version the slider I'm looking at implementing is http://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.html

I'm also using the bootstrap framework for the theme as well.

Any input would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the question is actually about page layout and there are 2 ways to achieve it.

1. Either put your slider into the `template/page/html/header.phtml` of your theme and then wrap it into the "if" clause which will check [if the current page is home or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403675/detect-home-page-in-magento-phtml-that-will-work-with-block-html-cache-enabled).
2. Modify `template/page/2columns-left.phtml` of your theme calling a new block between header and main content area. Of course you also have to define a block itself and add it under the `cms_index_index` layout handle.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer. I was kinda leaning towards the second way. 
Just a quick question about it though, if I add it to the 2columns-left.phtml won't it display on all pages set to 2 columns let?

Comment: No it won't as the block will be added to `cms_index_index` layout handle only.

Comment: ah cool, would I be best adding the slider to a static block and calling the static block. Sorry if these question seem pretty basic. I'm still just learning and would like to do it the most practical way as possible.

Comment: Adding a slider to static block is a good idea when you slider is pretty static.

Answer (score 0):

you can just edit CMS page, or if you want more advanced homepage, you can create new page template.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates